# Alt codes on Surface Book 2

Tags: microsoft-surface, numpad

I have a new Surface Book 2 and couldn't find how to enter alt+numpad codes for special characters on the hardware keyboard that comes with it. Is it possible to activate the numpad on the surface book 2 and otherwise, how can you enter special characters and be productive?

Comment: Are you trying to enter these characters in a specific program, like Word?

Comment: @CharlieRB I basically use text editors and IDE's and webbrowsers. I don't use word a lot.

Comment: Are you talking laptop or tablet mode? In laptop mode, does alt+(numbers at top of the keyboard) work?

Comment: @CharlieRB I am talking about laptop mode with the physical keyboard. Alt+numbers on top does not work.

Comment: Try this : Hold down Alt on your Type Cover while using the number pad of the On-Screen Keyboard (not the Touch Keyboard). Or you could use the Character Map.

Comment: I was hoping for an option build into the Surface book or Windows. I guess I need a keyboard remapping tool to create a virtual numpad when holding down alt+fn

Answer (score 3):

Try the touch keyboard:

The Touch Keyboard button appears just to the left of the clock, on the right side of the taskbar. If it's not visible, right-click any empty space on the taskbar to open the taskbar customization menu and then click the Show touch keyboard button option.

Click the Touch Keyboard button while working in any desktop program or Windows 10 app to slide up the on-screen keyboard. Here are a few things you can do:

- Click any letter or symbol and hold the mouse button down to see variations of that letter, including those with accents and diacritical marks. On the symbols layout, for example, click and hold the 1/2 symbol to see eight additional fractions.
- Click the button labeled &123 to change from the standard QWERTY layout to one filled with symbols. Use the right and left arrows just above that button to display a second screen full of symbols, including symbols for the Euro and British Pound on a U.S. English configuration.
- Click the smiley face to display a keyboard layout filled with emojis and emoticons. Use the icons to the right to change to different groups of emojis, each of which has additional layouts available using the left and right arrow below Tab.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this answer as well. This sounds like the fastest way for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> on your Type Cover while using the number pad of the On-Screen Keyboard (not the Touch Keyboard).

Or you could use the Character Map.

Comment: Did the On-Screen keyboard work for anyone? I tried it like this, but no luck: opening On-Screen Keyboard, choose Options > Turn on numeric key pad, press NumLock key, now type ALT and the code, e.g. ALT+148.

Answer (score 1):

Plug in an external number pad:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use fullsize mechanical keyboards at home and at work, but I asked the question because I want to use the mobile keyboard as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use the numbers at the top like numpad but as the comments mentioned already you might consider using the **Character map** or a program called [SymbSearch](https://leun4m.github.io/symbsearch/) - I have to admit I am one of the devs who developed this - we are currently working on a better version.

(I really don't want to make this an advert, but I would like to help you with these issue and it might be simply what you're searching for.)

**Edit:**
Another solution might be the program [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Such an application does work, but it is not as fast as being able to use the keyboard.